# Codeigniter: Undefined variable: sp and Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to insert the value of an input into the database, but I keep getting these two errors **Undefined variable: sp** and **Trying to get property of non-object** on the same line, I will post my MVC below in order for your verification. Any help will be much appreciated.

**MODEL**

```
<?php
class Sagepay_M extends MY_Model
{   
protected $_table_name = 'sagepay';
protected $_order_by = 'id';
public $rules = array(
    'id' => array(
        'field' => 'id', 
        'label' => 'ID', 
        'rules' => 'trim|callback__unique_name|required|xss_clean'
    ), 
    'sagepay_no' => array(
        'field' => 'sagepay_no', 
        'label' => 'sagepay_no', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
    ),

);

function __construct ()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function get_new(){
    $sp = new stdClass();
    $sp->id = '';
    $sp->sagepay_no = $this->getNextAutoId();
    return $sp; //UPDATE FROM ANSWER    
}

public function getNextAutoId(){
    $tem = $this->db->select('Max(id) as id')->get('naturescrm_sagepay')->result();
    $count = $tem[0]->id;
    $count++;
    $prefix = 'SAGE' ;
    return $prefix. str_pad($count, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ;
} 
}
?>
```

**VIEW**

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="sagepay_no">Sagepay ID</label>
                  <div  class="col-md-8"><?php echo form_input('sagepay_no', set_value('sagepay_no', $sp->sagepay_no),'class="form-control" id="sagepay_no" readonly="true"'); ?></div>
                </div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php
class Sagepay extends Agent_Controller
{
public function __construct ()
{
    parent::__construct();
    //datatable
    $this->load->model("customer_m");
    $this->load->model("call_log_m");
    $this->load->model("order_m");
    $this->load->model("sagepay_m");
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->load->library('datatables');
}

//finish
public function edit ($id = null)
{

    $this->load->model("call_log_m");
    $this->load->model("order_m");
    $this->load->model("sagepay_m");

    if($this->input->post("submit_btn")){
    $rules = $this->sagepay_m->rules;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        $data = $this->sagepay_m->array_from_post(array('id','sagepay_no'));
         $id = $this->sagepay_m->save($data, $id);
        redirect('agent/customer/edit/' .$id);
    }
    }
        $this->data['sp'] =  $this->sagepay_m->get_new($id);
        $this->data['subview'] = 'agent/customer/edit';
        $this->load->view('agent/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Where do you have the error ? In your view ?

Comment: Yes, both of these errors come up in the view

Comment: Show us the `var_dump($this->data);` just before the load->view.

Comment: Nothing is loading `var_dump($this->data);
$this->load->view('agent/_layout_main', $this->data);`

Comment: Mark (note) the line in code that produces the error. And change class and file name to `Sagepay_m` - lower "m".

Answer (score 0):

You don't return your object in your model :

```
public function get_new(){
    $sp = new stdClass();
    $sp->id = '';
    $sp->sagepay_no = $this->getNextAutoId();   

    return $sp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'll solve your problem, but in your controller, you have $id as an argument to the get_new method:

```
 $this->data['sp'] =  $this->sagepay_m->get_new($id);
```

Whereas in your model, the get_new method doesn't have it:

```
public function get_new(){
```

Comment: Whether I remove the `$id` in the `get_new` function or include it in the `public function get_new($id)` The error still remains.

Comment: I don't see `$this->data` initialized anywhere. Try changing all the instances to `$data`, `$data['sp'], etc maybe?

Comment: Doesn't work in spite of changing `$this->data` to `$data`

Comment: Is `$this->data['subview']`available in your view? What happens if you define `$this->data['sp']`yourself, instead of using the model's function? Also, there are two semi-colons at the end of your model...